# Trouble with Brother Printer using Terminal Server

Tags: windows, printer

I have printer redirection enabled on a terminal server and a Brother HL-6180DW printer, which has a second tray with legal size paper. On a local computer, both trays are available after adding it via printer properties, with the second listed as Legal size under Paper Source Setting, and printing on legal size paper works automatically. In the terminal services session, Tray 2 is not added, and the option to add it or auto-detect is greyed out.

Tray 2 can be added by selecting that printer from an administrative session and adding or auto-detecting, but it does not detect that it is legal size (it shows undefined) and does not detect the serial number. Trying to print on legal size paper from within the session just defaults to Tray 1, which is letter paper.

Clients are connecting from Windows 7 computers, both 32 and 64 bit.

How can I have tray 2 be detected so that clients can print correctly, especially for Legal size?

Comment: Welcome to the wonderful world of Terminal Services Printing! what a headache!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have run into this quite a few times. Printer redirection sometimes doesn't work very well, possibly because the driver being used on the terminal server isn't the exact same version as that on the local machine. Even then, it seems to have bugs.

Adding the printer to the terminal server itself is what usually gets all of the features to work properly. We set it with a static IP, then do it as a TCP/IP port:

Devices and Printers, Add a printer, Add a local printer, Create a new port -> Standard TCP/IP Port

Another alternative (if it's not a networked printer) is to share the printer from the local machine, then add it to the server.

Answer (score 0):

If the printer can be configured locally on the remote host then that is the best option.

The tray settings may not be accessible due to the default redirected printer security settings. You could try to enable the easy print driver which will use the local printer's settings for printing but, print jobs may not render correctly in some programs.

You could also use this PowerShell script to re-create the redirected printer queue giving the user permission to manage the printer.

https://github.com/zniezelski/Printerceptor/releases/

Zach